# What's wrong with my usage of `enumerateDates`?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to use `enumerateDates(startingAfter:matching:matchingPolicy:repeatedTimePolicy:direction:using:)`  to list all first days of months between two dates. However, I find it didn't return the last date as what I expected.

Here's the code snippet. I set the `endDate` as a random time on 2023/1/1. I thought it should also include `2023/1/1` in its output, but seems it ignored it. Is it an time zone issue because I'm in UTC+8?

```swift
let calendar = Calendar.current
let startDate = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2022, month: 10, day: 2))!
let endDate = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2023, month: 1, day: 1, hour: 12))!
let firstDayOfMonth = DateComponents(day: 1)
calendar.enumerateDates(startingAfter: endDate, matching: firstDayOfMonth, matchingPolicy: .strict, direction: .backward) { result, exactMatch, stop in
    if let date = result {
        if date < startDate {
            stop = true
        } else {
            print(date)
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
// I expect a `2022-12-31 16:00:00 +0000` here!
2022-11-30 16:00:00 +0000
2022-10-31 16:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: Set day to 2 and remove hour when creating `endDate` works for me.

Comment: The same with my UTC+1 timezone. I don't know why that happens, but I have seen more than one “bug report” about the enumerateDates method on this site.